# Set Checkbox to Off in Simpletest

Tags: php, simpletest

In one of my testcases using the simpletest webtester, I'd like to unset a checkbox.

From the documentation, it seems like setField should do it, but so far it hasn't worked. The documentation isn't really clear on how it works with a single checkbox, but I've tried a couple different settings with no success.

`setField('name','')`, `setField('name','off')`, and `setField('name', array())` don't appear to work.

How do I set a checkbox to unchecked in simpletest?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `setField('name', false)` unchecks a checkbox.